# i dont know why i am getting this the file exists but still showing the errors

Tags: java

Print the name of all directory located in the path “D:\file” and read all the contents of “D:\file \new.txt” file using BufferedReader and write it to another file copyOfNew.txt file using BufferedWriter.in the same location.

Here is the code :-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String dirName = "D:\\file";

        Files.list(new File(dirName).toPath())
                .limit(10)
                .forEach(path -> {
                    System.out.println(path);
                });
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:\\file\new.txt");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {

            // read line by line
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("copyOfNew.txt");
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer)) {

    bw.write(dirName);

}        catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
}
    }
}
```

Errors i am getting : -

```
D:\file\new.txt
IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\file
ew.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: `"D:\\file\new.txt"` should be `dirName + "\\new.txt"` and `"copyOfNew.txt"` should be `dirName + "\\copyOfNew.txt"`. The **FileWriter** and **BufferedWriter** declaration should be **above** the reading **while** loop and directly under the `System.out.println(line);` should be: `bw.append(line + System.lineSeparator());`. Don't forget to close your reader and writer unless **Try With Resources** is used.

Comment: I can only guess what you are asking when reading the title of this question. Please show some more effort: "I" should be written as a capital letter, the following sentence doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java compiler is replacing \n in the file path `"D:\\file\new.txt"` with a line break.

To avoid that and to simplify everything, use the platform independent directory separator character / instead of the windows-only character \:

```
reader = new FileReader("D:/file/new.txt")
```

Using a double back slash like in `"D:\\file\\new.txt"` also works, but you have to remember to use it consistently

Comment: Do you mean why does the compiler replace \\n with a line break? Because that's how you put a line break within a string

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `\n` to `\\n`, otherwise you add a newline, as you can see in the exception cause.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean, you can't write the file?

Comment: actually i want to write another file but its not working.Plz see the last lines of code

Answer (score 1):

The string literal is interpreting `\n` as a newline (and `\\` as `\`).  Each back-slash needs to be escaped:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("D:\\\\file\\new.txt")
```

Escaping with a back-slash tells the parser that the following character (in this case another back-slash) should be used as a literal part of the string and not a special character.